# PHP email attachments

Tags: php, email-attachments

I'm trying to send emails with multiple attachments.

This is an example:
`$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: Test <test@test.com>\r\n";

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "Test Email\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: text/x-csv; name=\"1.csv\"\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"1.csv\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $csvfile1 . "\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "Test Email\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: text/x-csv; name=\"2.csv\"\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"2.csv\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $csvfile2 . "\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "Test Email\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: text/x-csv; name=\"3.csv\"\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"3.csv\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $csvfile3 . "\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";`

And I get some strange characters at the end of the csv files, something like this:
`w־סֽד·ֽסמ׳fק־ןo,

‰z{­©}ךֺxn+¢”j״¶'Eט²¶*Jײֻrֵz°¶+·$j״¶'5ל†·u+¶+‰ֻ{²װj״¶',`

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find your life easier if you avoid reinventing the wheel and use something like [phpmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer) which handles this for you.

Comment: Did you try to output the content of `$header`? It would be easier for debugging and you would see that you have some extra new lines in some places and some missing in other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- There should be only one new line before a boundary. You have 2.
- You should have 2 dashes only after the last boundary.
- There are 2 places where `Content-Transfer-Encoding` needs to have a new line before.
- You *may* have forgotten to base64 encode your files.
- Your code looks like the result of some terrible copy-pasting.
- Maybe other.

As El Yobo said in a comment, maybe you should try using a library for this.